# Removal of override, not able to view fragment b

Tags: java, android, methods, overriding

I'm going through this "Beginning Android Development" book. I get to the Fragments section and I follow the code as show, but my compiler gives me an error.
                   MainActivity.java
    package com.example.fragmentsdemo;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle saveInstanceState){
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_frag, null, false);
    return view;
}

}
```

The error begins at "public view" and states "The method ... of type MainActivity.java must override or implement a supertype method

The two XML files are below for completion...

```
                      activity_main.xml
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<fragment
    android:id="@+id/fragment1"
    android:name="com.example.fragmentsdemo.MyFragment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    tools:layout="@layout/my_frag" />

</RelativeLayout>


              my_frag.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World from Fragment!"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Now, when I remove @Override it will run, but I do not see the text "Hello World from Fragment!" there. Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you creating an Activity or a Fragment? You should extend Fragment if thats what you are building

Comment: Does the Activity class contain a public or protected method with the signature `View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle saveInstanceState)`  ?

Comment: I did noticed that I typed Activity instead of Fragment (probably auto-pilot), after changing that nothing changed. I get the same error message.

I'm not sure what you mean regarding public or protected method. The entire code you see there is what is to be ran from the book.

Comment: @Crazylegs888 Your activity should override an `onCreate` method like this --> `@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); // your code here }`. I suggest you create the activity using Eclipse or Android Studio (instead of copy-pasting from a book), because it'll auto-create the methods you need for you.

Answer (score 0):

The method `onCreateView` in your parent class `Activity` accepts the following parameters:

- `View`, `String`, `Context`, `AttributeSet`
- `String`, `Context`, `AttributeSet`

It seems you need to extend `Fragment` instead `Activity`

[Fragment documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20android.os.Bundle))

In your `activity_main.xml`, in the fragment block, the fragment name should be the name of your `Fragment` class.